# Regex using sed or Perl to comment XML Block

Tags: xml, perl, sed

I'm trying to comment a section at web.xml inside openAM using only `sed` or `perl -pi` (the only tools available to me).

So, Ill copy here:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AgentConfigurationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/agentconfig/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VersionServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ccversion/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FSServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/federation/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

but I'm trying to comment only the `<servlet-mapping>...</servlet-mapping>` (but only the one with the /ccversion. I tried everything and couldn't make it work.

What I tried:

```
sed -e "s/(<servlet-mapping>[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*\/ccversion.*[\r\n]+.*)/<\!-- \$1 -->/"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use XML-aware tools to process XML. You mention Perl, there are several XML-handling modules available.

But, if you insist, try the following at your own risk:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{.*\K(<servlet-mapping>\s*.*?<url-pattern>/ccversion/.*?</servlet-mapping>)}{<!-- $1 -->}s' file.xml
```

- `-0777` reads the file in the "slurp mode", i.e. it reads in the whole file, not processing it line by line;
- The initial `.*\K` is there to match and forget everything before the `<servlet-mapping>` we're interested in;
- The `.*?` needs the question mark ("frugal quantifier") to only match to the nearest `<url-pattern>`, and similarly the second one to match to the nearest `</servlet-mapping>`, instead of matching up to the last one;
- The final `}s` modifier changes dots to also match newlines.

BTW, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) I happen to maintain, the same can be acieved with

```
open file.xml ;
for my $sm in //servlet-mapping[url-pattern="/ccversion/*"]
    xinsert comment {"$sm"} replace $sm ;
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because somebody had to say it and I need the practice :) Here's how to do it using libxml identity transform:

comment.xsl

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/info/servlet-mapping[url-pattern[text()='/ccversion/*']]">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!-- </xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> --&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`xsltproc comment.xsl input.xml`

output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AgentConfigurationServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/agentconfig/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>VersionServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ccversion/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FSServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/federation/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</info>
```